# Where to keep state which will show and hide dialog in android compose screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I have a screen with a button which will execute a network call. I need to show an alert dialog on the same screen based on the network error.

Sample code:

```
// AAViewModel.kt
fun fetchWeather(){
    //......
    //Error 
}
```

```
// compose screen 
@Composable 
fun showWeather(){
    //  .....
    if(dialogState.visible.value){
        dialog.title 
        dialog.message
        //Show dialog 
    }
}
```

The network call returns an error code, so we must set the title and error message based on the error code.

1. Where is the right place to keep dialogState -- in the AAviewModel or the showWeather function?
2. As per https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state-hoisting document,
   Ui logic should be kept under compose, and business logic should go under ViewModel.
   Is the showing dialog a UI logic or a business logic, and should the construction of my alert happen in ViewModel or the compose function itself?

Comment: `Is the showing dialog a UI logic or a business logic` well, what do you think it is ? genuinely curious to hear your opinion on this

Comment: @a_local_nobody I am confused of it so only came to SO to get some clarity , in my view deciding to show or not is business logic but how and where is UI logic .

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the `AlertDialog` depends on a state updated within the view model, combined with a title and a message, and it's only being observed, and probably dismissed by the UI. So handling this state is considered to be a `business logic` and it must be kept in the view model. Here is an example implementation:

Firstly, adapt the current state to a combined one in form of a data class, which contains visibility, title, and message values, marked with `androidx.compose.runtime.Stable` annotation to reduce recompositions:

```kotlin
@Stable
data class AlertDialogState(
    val visible: Boolean = false,
    val title: String = "",
    val message: String = ""
)
```

Then, declare the state inside the view model as a private `MutableStateFlow`, with a public read-only `StateFlow` for the UI, and a function to dismiss the dialog:

```kotlin
private val _alertDialogState = MutableStateFlow(AlertDialogState())
val alertDialogState = _alertDialogState.asStateFlow()

fun dismissAlertDialog() {
    _alertDialogState.update { it.copy(visible = false) }
}
```

Now, I don't know how the error handling is implemented, but I assume that the title and the message for the dialog are already declared and ready for implementation, so the state can be updated:

```kotlin
_alertDialogState.update {
    AlertDialogState(
        visible = true,
        title = title,
        message = errorMessage
    )
}
```

And finally, the UI composable implementation:

```kotlin
/// ...

val alertDialogState by viewModel.alertDialogState.collectAsState()

/// ...

if (alertDialogState.visible) {

    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = viewModel::dismissAlertDialog,
        title = { Text(text = alertDialogState.title) },
        text = { Text(text = alertDialogState.message) },
        confirmButton = {},
        dismissButton = {

            // Leave empty if you don't need a button.

            TextButton(
                onClick = viewModel::dismissAlertDialog,
                content = { Text(text = "Dismiss") }
            )

        }
    )

}

/// ...
```

Check out [this link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/dialog) for more information about dialogs in compose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, My alert dialogs titles will be decided based on error code send from server EX: 0001 is show title1 from strings , 0002 title3 from strings and 0003 title2 from strings. Is it good approach to move string logic to compose (String expect context)